# Python deploying to Heroku "version not available for this stack"

Tags: python, heroku, bots, reddit

Here is the log of the error. Any idea what to do?

the program is just a bot for reddit, and I have the Procfile, and the requirements.txt file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXJIh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Python 2.7.9 is not a valid runtime. You can use either `python-2.7.13`
 or `python-3.6.0`

See this for more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes